# Motherboard or CPU dead?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, troubleshooting

I have an Asus Z8NA-D6C Motherboard with dual sockets for Intel Xeon CPUs. When I go to power up the system, however, I receive no post beep codes unless I fully remove the RAM. Any suggestions?

CPU: 2x Intel E5620s
MOBO: Asus Z8NA-D6C
RAM: 2x Kingston ECC Registered 4gb
PSU: Corsair 750i
SSD: Samsung 250gb

Comment: Your motherboard supports ECC memory?

Comment: Yeah according to Asus's website: https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/Z8NAD6C/specifications/

Comment: Your memory is installed in the correct modules in a supported config?

Comment: The site says to use the two closest slots for a dual CPU but I've tried all the slots and no configuration seems to work

Comment: The CPUs and/or memory have been tested in another motherboard?

Comment: Please use another RAM instead of ECC Registered RAM for testing.

Comment: I have tried unbuffered non-ECC RAM and it gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new build?  Did it work prior to this issue?  When did this issue start?

When it is down to this level, I'd recommend purchasing a POST card like [THIS](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6UM2GS3082&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Accessories%20-%20Motherboards-_-9SIA6UM2GS3082&gclid=CjwKEAjwubK4BRC1xczKrZyj3mkSJAC6ntgrgkIBve0PjlVAadO61D-TOA5yH7D5OA1zlhQLQMXyuRoCmvjw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Using that, you can narrow down the issue a bit further.

Also, check that your PSU is providing the proper amount of power.

Comment: New build for me. The mobo is used but was working in another system. The issue started as soon as the first boot up. I will check the PSU. Thanks

Comment: With the post cards is one better over another?

Comment: How many watts should the two cpus pull during post?